# Asp.Net Session setting AFTER page load not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, session

**Initial Scenario :** Page loaded , Javascript runs to show a modal popup window.

**Requirement :** If the popup window is shown set a session value , this is done thru an AJAX jquery call to a handler.

**Expected Result:**When the user closes the modal and clicks on any other link on the main webpage , check if session is set , if true don't show popup again on the navigated page.

**Actual Result :** The value for the session coming back as null (intermittently)

*This issue is **NOT** seen when debugging the code .*

**Is there a problem with setting a session after page load thru' an ajax call (since the headers are already loaded) ?**

Also , in my case the check for session value happens on the master page.

I have checked to see that the handler call comes back with status 200 .

Even strange - This issue happens intermittently.

What am I missing ? Where is the session setting getting lost ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery as follow

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var x = '<%= Session["seen"] %>';
        if (x != "1") {
            $("#popup").show();
            '<%Session["seen"] = "1" %>';
        } 
});
```

or in your case use

```
'<%Session["seen"] = "1" %>';
```

on dialog close handler

Comment: Thank you @Thair , I will try this , but any reason why the ajax handler call will not work ?

Comment: I an not sure about your case . But maybe if you add trigger to the updatePanel and register the modal popup in it . . . .